# repeating jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have this HTML from Drupal

```
<span id="terms" style="visibility:hidden">
<ul class="links inline">
<li class="taxonomy_term_14 first"><a href="/taxonomy/term/14" rel="tag" title="National Site">national</a></li> 
<li class="taxonomy_term_2 last"><a href="/category/region/all/nyc" rel="tag" title="">nyc</a></li> 
</ul></span>
```

I am using this JQuery to get the text "nyc" from the second `<li>`.

```
var tagText = $("#terms li + li").text();
```

when I check to view tagText, document.write(tagtext) shows "nynynynynynynynynynynynynynynyny" instead of just "nyc." Why is it repeating?

Comment: Might I point out that you've got a `span` of id 'terms', but your jQuery selector's looking for an element of id 'tags'. This might be related to the problem you're experiencing. If `$('#tags li + li')` is changed to `$('#terms li + li')` it [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/spEFc/).

Comment: just edited that ID that was a typo and not the problem. I executed the code using the correct # terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or

```
$("#terms").find("ul li:last").text();
```

or

```
$("#terms").find("ul:last-child").text();
```

I believe both should work.

OR if you want to get fancy you cold use the `:nth-child(n)` selector (not 0 based)

Based on your question however...

`$("#terms li:last").text()` should do the trick.

Comment: great thanks, and idea why my sibling selector approach was causing the text to repeat?

Comment: I think the problem was that you were selecting a different set of `li`s altogether...

Comment: "I think the problem was that you were selecting a different set of `li`s."

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#terms").find(".taxonomy_term_2 last").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<span id="terms"` and in javascript there is `#tags`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the id `tags`, I only see `terms` in your HTML snippet. I assume the selector you meant to use was

```
$("#terms li:last").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

this can help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#terms li").click(function(){
        alert($(this).children('a').html());

    });
});
```

The html is

```
<span id="terms" >
<ul class="links inline">
<li class="taxonomy_term_14 first"><a href="#" rel="tag" title="National Site">national</a></li> 
<li class="taxonomy_term_2 last"><a href="#" rel="tag" title="nyc">nyc</a></li> 
</ul></span>
```